# PowerShell script to amend the row in existing CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, append

I'm trying to insert retrieved values into an existing CSV by using `-Append -Force`. However, it does not place it under the rows that I wanted it to. Anyway to solve this? Currently, the values are in row 12 to 17, but I want it to be in row 2 to 11. Column A to F are in an existing CSV while column G is what I want to input the values into.

Here is my current CSV output

[image]

Expected Output that I'm looking for:

[image]

And here is my current Powershell code:
[Current Powershell code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XemFH.png)

Comment: Please write your code, expected behaviour, error message, etc. directly into your question and not link them.

Comment: You need to loop through your CSV at the same time you are looping through the text file. Then use Add-Member to add the PolicyValue property to each row object. Then export the whole CSV without Append. You don’t show the code that creates or reads the CSV data with columns A-F